# What can I do to eliminate the error FindFit::nrjnum:?

Tags: fitting, complex, singularity

I am testing the "Power Law with finite-time singularity" hypothesis for world population growth for a project.

The data I'm using (same behaviour should also be exhibited by the stock market, thats why I am trying this with financial data):

```
raw = FinancialData["GE", All];
fraw = Flatten[raw];
data = Table[fraw[[4*i]], {i, 1, Length[raw]}]; (*extracting just the prices*)
```

I was trying the following regression model:

```
model = A + B*(c - x)^z;
```

And then the following curve fit method:

```
FindFit[data, {model}, {A, B, c, z}, x]
```

But I always get the result:

> Power::indet: "Indeterminate expression 0.^0. encountered." FindFit::nrjnum: "The Jacobian is not a matrix of real numbers at {A, B, c, z} = {1., 1., 1., 1.}. "
>
> {A -> 1., B -> 1., c -> 1., z -> 1.}

If I do a normal Power law regression, `FindFit` works perfectly, but the title of the project being "Power Law with finite-time singularity" I need to have the singularity `c` in the model and the main aim is to find when this singularity occurs.

Is there a way to use `FindFit` to get the correct answer? Or should I be using some other function?

I have seen other articles on this site concerning issues with `FindFit`, but none of them has helped me resolve this problem.

Remark: I have already tried the version belisarius has stated below, but the problem with that is that it gives me a `z > 0`. What I need is `z < 0` for `x = c` to be a singularity. So I also tried the following models: `A + B*Abs[c - x]^(-z)` and `A + B*(c - x)^(-z)` with `-z` instead of `z` but those just gave me like 15 other warnings.

Comment: Providing some sensible `data` would be a first step to reproduce/solve the problem.

Comment: @YvesKlett `data = Table[{x, 
    RandomReal[{0.9, 1.1}] + model /. {A -> 1, B -> 2, c -> 3, z -> 0.5}}, {x, 0, 3, .01}];` works for me.

Comment: @YvesKlett I have added my data source now.

Answer (score 3):

You may try something like:

```
raw = FinancialData["GE", All];
fraw = Flatten[raw];
data = Table[fraw[[4*i]], {i, 1, Length[raw]}];(*extracting just the prices*)

model = A + B*Abs[c - x]^z;
fit = FindFit[data, {model}, {A, B, c, z}, x];
modelf = Function[{t}, Evaluate[model /. fit]]
Show[Plot[modelf[x], {x, 0, 12000}], ListPlot@data]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Perhaps you should explicitly point out that you added an `Abs` to the model, and explain why that helps.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries The OP stated that s/he has been given a project name, so I infer that this is some kind of homework. So, just teaching to fish

Comment: @belisarius Thanks for your reply! As a matter of fact I did try the version you have stated, but the problem with that is that it gives me a `z > 0`. What I need is `z < 0` for `x = c` to be a singularity. So I also tried the following models: `A + B*Abs[c - x]^(-z)` and `A + B*(c - x)^(-z)` but those just gave me like 15 other warnings.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like the data extends to the right of the singularity. Is it acceptable to simply remove that part of the data? It doesn't look like it could possibly fit the model.

```
FindFit[data[[;; 9500]], model, {{A, 0}, {B, 10^9}, {c, 10000}, {z, -2}}, x]
(*  {A -> -0.0521369, B -> 1.54292*10^10, c -> 11142.5, z -> -2.71708}  *)

Show[ListLinePlot[data], Plot[model /. %, {x, 1, 12000}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}]]
```

[image]