# How to solve this FindFit::nrlnum:

Tags: fitting

the following code show error message

> FindFit::nrlnum: "The function value {6.71759 -9.36268*10^-8\
>   I,6.51797 -8.42641*10^-8\ I,6.31789 -7.49014*10^-8\ I,6.1179
>   -6.55387*10^-8\ I,5.91794 -5.61761*10^-8\ I,5.71797 -4.68134*10^-8\ I,<<5>>,4.53457 +0.\ I,4.35846 +0.\ I,4.21276 +0.\ I,4.12436 +0.\
>   I,4.12268 +0.\ I}\n is not a list of real numbers with dimensions
>   {16} at {a,b} = {1.,1.}. "

```
FindFit[{{-1.9999999999999993`, -8.71758682396597`}, \
    {-1.7999999999999994`, -8.317969980679658`}, {-1.5999999999999996`, \
    -7.9178913932701125`}, {-1.3999999999999995`, -7.517895681098703`}, \
    {-1.1999999999999997`, -7.117935726160363`}, {-0.9999999999999997`, \
    -6.717970679612214`}, {-0.7999999999999997`, -6.318075235251766`}, \
    {-0.5999999999999999`, -5.918333526484718`}, {-0.3999999999999999`, \
    -5.518978976322539`}, {-0.1999999999999999`, -5.120597037968602`}, \
    {0.`, -4.724630562634576`}, {0.1999999999999997`, \
    -4.334574650968856`}, {0.3999999999999999`, -3.9584626158001357`}, \
    {0.6000000000000001`, -3.6127563661613884`}, {0.7999999999999998`, \
    -3.324357131929245`}, {0.9999999999999994`, -3.1226771789912595`}}, 
     a x^b, {a, b}, x]
```

I tried the method [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20539/what-can-i-do-to-eliminate-the-error-findfitnrjnum), but all didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
data = {{-1.9999999999999993`, -8.71758682396597`}, \
{-1.7999999999999994`, -8.317969980679658`}, {-1.5999999999999996`, \
-7.9178913932701125`}, {-1.3999999999999995`, -7.517895681098703`}, \
{-1.1999999999999997`, -7.117935726160363`}, {-0.9999999999999997`, \
-6.717970679612214`}, {-0.7999999999999997`, -6.318075235251766`}, \
{-0.5999999999999999`, -5.918333526484718`}, {0.`, \
-4.724630562634576`}, {-0.3999999999999999`, -5.518978976322539`}, \
{-0.1999999999999999`, -5.120597037968602`}, {0.1999999999999997`, \
-4.334574650968856`}, {0.3999999999999999`, -3.9584626158001357`}, \
{0.6000000000000001`, -3.6127563661613884`}, {0.7999999999999998`, \
-3.324357131929245`}, {0.9999999999999994`, -3.1226771789912595`}};
model = a x^b;
f = FindFit[data, model, {a, b}, x,NormFunction -> (Norm[#, Infinity] &)]

(* {a -> 1.90367964288013, b -> 1.10590831050973} *)
```

Use different Norm function. `Gradient -> "FiniteDifference"` is not really needed, I just left it there, since help says to use it when getting singularity. But it will work without it here if you use infinity norm.

But the fit does not look good. There is a constant offset, and does not generate go to the negative x as the data does:

```
 Show[ListPlot[data], Plot[model /. f, {x, -1, 2}], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting, your method works in MM9 while not work in MM8. And I really don't understand that the data points are so trivial, why I have to add so many options to make the fit work?

Comment: Oh,I understand why. I made a silly mistake, what a shame! I give Mathematica an improper fitting function, I should have add a constant term. Thank you Nasser!

Answer (score 1):

The negative values for the model chosen pose the problem.
There are a number of approaches noting the data:
1. a linear model (this give quite a reasonable fit)
2. Using non linear model fit with your model but transforming your data
3. Perhaps, the simplest  approach and using your desired `FindFit` is to transform your data and back transform.

```
ft = FindFit[# + {2, 9} & /@ data, a x^b, {a, b}, x]
```

where data is your dataset.

This yields:

```
{a -> 2.33187, b -> 0.862647}
```

You can visually assess the fit (the other properties allow diagnostics, R^2 etc):

```
Show[ListPlot[data], 
 Plot[Evaluate[(a (x + 2)^b - 9) /. ft], {x, -2, 1}]]
```

[image]