# Understanding and solving a problem with FindFit

Tags: fitting, warning-messages

I have a set of data which I give here

```
data = {{0.294320000000000026`7., 23.8843734496254604949`7.}, {0.6795160000000000089`7., 23.8843611997525542279`7.}, 
   {1.0502000000000000224`7., 23.8843489498796444082`7.}, {1.4071700000000000319`7., 23.8843367000067381412`7.}, {1.7511799999999999589`7., 23.8843244501338318742`7.}, 
   {2.0829300000000001702`7., 23.8843122002609220544`7.}, {2.4030499999999999083`7., 23.8842999503880157874`7.}, {2.7121499999999998387`7., 23.8842877005151095204`7.}, 
   {3.0107800000000000118`7., 23.8842754506421997007`7.}, {3.2994699999999999029`7., 23.8842632007692934337`7.}, {3.5787100000000000577`7., 23.884250950896383614`7.}, 
   {3.8489599999999999369`7., 23.884238701023477347`7.}, {4.1106400000000000716`7., 23.88422645115057108`7.}, {4.3641500000000004178`7., 23.8842142012776612603`7.}, 
   {4.6098699999999999122`7., 23.8842019514047549933`7.}, {4.8481500000000004036`7., 23.8841897015318487263`7.}, {6.8864700000000000912`7., 23.8840672028027718454`7.}, 
   {8.4512300000000006861`7., 23.8839447040736949646`7.}, {9.6903000000000005798`7., 23.8838222053446180837`7.}, {10.6958000000000001961`7., 23.8836997066155447556`7.}, 
   {11.5281000000000002359`7., 23.8835772078864678747`7.}, {15.6127000000000002444`7., 23.8823522205957097242`7.}, 
   {17.1147999999999989029`7., 23.8811272333049551264`7.}, {17.9021000000000007901`7., 23.8799022460141969759`7.}, 
   {18.3740999999999985448`7., 23.8786772587234423781`7.}, {18.6981000000000001648`7., 23.8774522714326842276`7.}, 
   {18.9327000000000005286`7., 23.8762272841419260772`7.}, {19.117100000000000648`7., 23.8750022968511714794`7.}, 
   {19.8338999999999998636`7., 23.8627524239436006326`7.}, {20.0574000000000012278`7., 23.8505025510360333385`7.}, 
   {20.1506000000000007333`7., 23.8382526781284624917`7.}, {20.2182999999999992724`7., 23.8260028052208951976`7.}, 
   {20.2663000000000010914`7., 23.8137529323133279036`7.}, {20.3024999999999984368`7., 23.8015030594057606095`7.}, 
   {20.3335000000000007958`7., 23.7892531864981897627`7.}, {20.359200000000001296`7., 23.7770033135906224686`7.}, 
   {20.3817999999999983629`7., 23.7647534406830516218`7.}, {20.5414999999999992042`7., 23.6422547116073644702`7.}, 
   {20.6695999999999990848`7., 23.5197559825316808713`7.}, {20.7867999999999994998`7., 23.3972572534559937196`7.}, 
   {20.9030999999999984595`7., 23.274758524380306568`7.}, {22.0936999999999983402`7., 22.0497712336234528152`7.}, {23.4103999999999992099`7., 20.824783942866591957`7.}, 
   {24.8888999999999995794`7., 19.5997966521097346515`7.}, {26.5626999999999995339`7., 18.3748093613528737933`7.}, 
   {28.4742999999999994998`7., 17.1498220705960164878`7.}, {30.6789999999999984936`7., 15.9248347798391591823`7.}, 
   {33.2490999999999985448`7., 14.6998474890823001004`7.}, {36.2854999999999989768`7., 13.474860198325442795`7.}, 
   {39.9273000000000024556`7., 12.2498729075685837131`7.}, {44.376300000000000523`7., 11.0248856168117264076`7.}, {49.935099999999998488`7., 9.7998983260548673258`7.}, 
   {57.0788999999999973056`7., 8.5749110352980082439`7.}, {66.5995999999999952479`7., 7.3499237445411500502`7.}, {79.9188999999999936108`7., 6.1249364537842918566`7.}, 
   {99.8800999999999987722`7., 4.8999491630274336629`7.}, {133.0889999999999986358`7., 3.6749618722705750251`7.}, 
   {199.2379999999999995453`7., 2.4499745815137168314`7.}, {393.9680000000000177351`7., 1.2249872907568584157`7.}}
```

And I am trying to fit to a model. In order to do so, I have the following

```
fitfunction[x_] := a + b*Log[c*x + d*x^2]
sltnmodel = FindFit[data, fitfunction[x], {a, b, c, d, e}, x, MaxIterations -> Infinity]
Show[ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> {{-170, 500}, {-0.1, 25}}, PlotMarkers -> Style["\[FilledCircle]", 11, Red], BaseStyle -> {13, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"}, 
   AxesLabel -> {"\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(g\), \(2\)]\)", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(M\), \(B\)]\)/\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(f\), \(\[Pi]\)]\)"}, Joined -> False], 
  Plot[fitfunction[x] /. sltnmodel, {x, 0, 600}, PlotRange -> {{-170, 500}, {-0.1, 25}}, PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Black}]]
```

The result of the plot is shown below.

[image: The plot]

So the fitting needs some more work.

The problem is that if add something to the existing Log fit it gives the following error message.

[image]

I tried to use the answer that was given [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38191/how-to-solve-this-findfitnrlnum), but it does not fix the problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: what do you mean: if add something?

Comment: Interesting that both FindFit and NonlinearModelFit give the same (bad?) fitted parameters.

Comment: @Fraccalo I mean that you can take the piece that is written in the code above and try to add f x^2 for example or any other function

Comment: @Lotus does this mean that Mma is not able to find the correct values or that the guess is bad for the given set of data?

Comment: @A_user_with_NoName try adding Abs[] within the Log argument. I think the problem arises from mathematica trying to compute negative logs

Comment: Using Fraccalo's comment above, a + b*Log[Abs[c*x + d*x^2 e x^4]] makes it better. It seems that you should split the data into two sets. I will elaborate in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, it looks like the problem is the Log trying to evaluate when the argument is negative. Adding Abs in the argument might help.

Also, the model itself doesn't seem to match the data: are you sure that data should follow that function?

It looks to me that Exp[-x^(1/2)] fits the data better:

```
fitfunction[x_] := b*Exp[-c*x^(1/2) + d]
sltnmodel = 
 FindFit[data[[27 ;;]], 
  fitfunction[x], {{a, 0}, {b, 1}, {c, .01}, {d, 0}, {e, 1}}, x, 
  MaxIterations -> Infinity]
```

> [image]

Please note that you can add an additional vertical offset "a", remove the horizontal offset "d" etc (if it makes sense in your model).

Also, I'm neglecting the first 26 data points when fitting as they seem to arise from a different distribution: probably your model should take this into account as well, but without any prior knowledge of what we are looking at, it's hard to tell.

Anyhoo, I hope that this will give you enough material to play with, and to understand your data better.

Comment: Exactly what I meant by splitting the data set. Great !

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I actually had in mind to split the FitFunction in two sets in the end and match, but I started facing the problem I mentioned and for my purposes, it is the points after the first 26 that are more interesting.