# FindFit (Jacobian Error)

Tags: fitting

I, like others before me, am struggling with `FindFit`. So, I tried a simple example.

```
data2 = Table[{x, x^2}, {x, -2, 2, 0.1}]

ListPlot[data2]

FindFit[data2, a x^d, {a, d}, x]
```

Which then produces the error:

> ```
> "FindFit::nrjnum: The Jacobian is not a matrix of real numbers at {a,d} = {1.,1.}"
> ```

The plot looks good, but the error message doesn't mean anything to me. Where the bottom of the range of `x` is greater than zero, FindFit `enter code here`works okay, and gives the right result. When the bottom of the range is zero or less, the error message comes back.

Two questions please. What does the error message mean, and how can I avoid running into it?

Comment: OTOH, [What can I do to eliminate the error FindFit::nrjnum:?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20539/what-can-i-do-to-eliminate-the-error-findfitnrjnum) uses `Abs` to solve the problem.  In any case, this question is related to these two.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two reasons why it doesn't work.

You have negative `x` values.  Raising these to fractional `d` powers gives complex results.  For this reason it is not sensible to use the form `a x^d` for fitting this data.  However, you could use `a Abs[x]^d` instead.

With this change it still won't work.  The other reason is that `FindFit` work by minimizing (using `FindMinimum`) the sum of the squares errors.  The data includes the value `x==0` so the sum of the squared errors will include `0^d` as a subexpression.  Most minimization methods will calculate the gradient of the function to minimize.  Mathematica will try to do this symbolically.  The derivative of `0^d` is going to yield `Indeterminate` through evaluating to 0^d Log[0], which ultimately causes the trouble.

Two possible solutions are: Remove the point where `x==0`

```
FindFit[DeleteCases[data2, {x_, _} /; x == 0], a Abs[x]^d, {a, d}, x]

(* ==> {a -> 1., d -> 2.} *)
```

Or use a minimization method that doesn't calculate the gradient:

```
FindFit[data2, a Abs[x]^d, {a, d}, x, Method -> "PrincipalAxis"]

(* ==> {a -> 1., d -> 2.} *)
```

Comment: Oh, you beat me to it.  The reason `a Abs[x]^d` doesn't work is because the Jacobian is `Indeterminate` at `x = 0.`  Delete that from `data` and it works.

Comment: @MichaelE2 It gives me the same error

Comment: Nice analysis. +1

Comment: @MichaelE2 I still don't understand something.  The derivative of `0^d` is well defined if `d>0`.  So if it is approximated numerically (not symbolically) then there shouldn't be a problem.  Yet all the [methods](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/UnconstrainedOptimizationIntroductionLocalMinimization.html) except PrincipalAxis fail because of it.  How can we force Mma to approximate the gradient purely numerically other than making the function a numerical black box?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Also, `FindMinimum[0^d + 2^d - 4, {d, 1}, Method -> "Newton"]` fails as expected but `FindMinimum[0^d + 2^d - 4, {d, 1}, Method -> "QuasiNewton"]` works.  So why doesn't QuasiNewton work for the fitting?  And why does `FindMinimum[N[0^d + 2^d - 4], {d, 1}, Method -> "Newton"]` *not* fail?

Comment: The Jacobian `D[a Abs[x]^d, {{a, d}}]` is `{Abs[x]^d, a Abs[x]^d Log[Abs[x]]}`, which is `Indeterminate` at `x = 0`.  Any derivative-based algorithm is likely to have trouble.  The `"PrincipalAxis"` method is derivative-free. It's the only derivative-free method I know....

Comment: Neither `FindMinimum` method works for me.  `"QuasiNewton"` uses the (symbolic) first derivative and numerically estimates the second derivative (or Hessian).

Comment: @MichaelE2 "QuasiNewton uses the (symbolic) first derivative and numerically estimates the second derivative (or Hessian)." <-- OK, that explains it.  This is only a problem when doing the derivative symbolically.

Comment: @belisarius  Szabolcs's code that deletes `0` works for me.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I'm trying `data2 = Table[{x, x^2}, {x, -2, 2, 0.1}];
FindFit[DeleteCases[data2, {x_, _} /; x == 0], a x^d, {a, d}, x]` That's why we get different results